# Select blockquote text on double click script

Tags: javascript, select, quotes

I'm trying to add double click select in `.blockqoute > .bck1`. But, it seems that I'm doing it incorrectly.

I have mader many attempts, and most of them look like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectText(blockquote) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(blockquote));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(blockquote));
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I was trying to add it in many ways and places but it wont work. I'm totally beginner in scripts so if anyone can help me a bit ill be grateful.

Also, I have 7 different looks of `blockqoute` and I want to apply only on 1 of them.

Comment: Hace you tried to use addEventListener with a dbclick function?